# listing packages in Debian, a la `dpkg -l`, but including the package origin/source

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I want to list all packages of the form

```
$ dpkg -l libav\*
```

but in addition to this output, I would like the origin/source (I'm not sure of the preferred term) of each package. If the package doesn't correspond to any source, it should say unknown or similar. Off the top of my head, the most promising approach would be to use [dctrl-tools](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/dctrl-tools), but I'm not sure how to go about it. For background, I was trying to debug a library mismatch with ffmpeg. See [Debian bug report - ffmpeg: backport of 4:0.6.1-5 from unstable produces WARNING: library configuration mismatch](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=619530). The bug report is no longer an issue, but I'm still interested in this question.

Just to be clear on the format, this should look something like

```
ii  libavahi-client-dev  0.6.27-2+squeeze1  Development files for the Avahi client library  squeeze
ii  libavcodec-dev       4:0.6.1-5          Development files for libavcodec                unstable
```

If the same package is available in multiple categories, ie. in both squeeze and testing, then the *lowest* / *oldest* category available should be used. In this case, squeeze.

Comment: `apt-cache policy <package>` gives relevant info; I'm too lazy to produce an actual script to link it to `dpkg`'s output.

Comment: I'm not sure the origin can be reported reliably. (I don't think it's recorded when the install happens.) For stable releases you can compare the installed versions against the archive, but for packages from unstable the installed version may not be in the archive any more.

Comment: @Andy: This information is recorded in apt's database, since `apt-cache policy` reports it, as pointed out by 9000 above. If the package is not in any archive, it should be reported as unknown. See my updated question above.

Comment: The information is not recorded. `apt-cache policy` is showing where the package can currently be obtained from, not where it was originally obtained from when installed.

Comment: @Arrowmaster: Incorrect. `apt-cache policy` is reading the information in apt's database, which is (usually) updated via `apt-get update` or `aptitude update` (not sure if these actually update the same stuff). So it is as current as the most recent update.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Andy and Arrowmaster are correct: apt doesn't track the information, it shows you where the package can be installed now. For example, if you installed a package from unstable and it now happens to be in testing, the only information you'll get is “testing”.

Comment: @Gilles: my understanding is that the information about where a particular package is available corresponds to the most recent "update". If you installed a package from unstable, and did not run an update after that, the local info would still say the package was available from unstable, though this was in fact not the case. So, the package could 'now' be in testing, but (for example) apt-cache would incorrectly report it as still being in unstable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dpkg doesn't track this information. Where you got each `.deb` file is not its concern.

Apt doesn't track this information either, but it knows where you can now get the package, which is good enough.

As [9000](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3633/9000) wrote in a comment, `apt-cache policy '^libav'` shows you what versions of packages with names matching the regexp `^libav` are installed or available. The output isn't particularly convenient to parse, but here's a minimally tested script that gives approximately the format you want:

```
{ LC_CTYPE=C apt-cache policy '^libav'; echo .; } | perl -l -ne '
    if (!/^ /) {
        if (defined $version) {print "$package: $version unknown"}
        s/: *$//; $package=$_; $installed=1; $version=undef;
    }
    if (/^ *Installed: *\(none\)$/) {$installed=0}
    if ($installed && /^ \*+ +([^ ]+)/) {$version=$1}
    if (/^     [^ ]/) {$version=undef}
    if ($installed && defined $version && /^ +[0-9]+ +[^ ]+ +([^ \/]+)/) {
        print "$package: $version $1";
        $version=undef;
    }
'
```

Another way to the information you're asking for is with `aptitude versions`. Again, the minimally-tested snippet below gives roughly the desired format. The pattern `"^libav" ~i` matches packages that are installed and whose name matches the given regexp.

```
aptitude versions '"^libav" ~i' |
awk -vRS= '{if ($6 !~ /[^0-9]/) {$6="unknown"}
            print $3, $2, $5, $6}'
```

There's also a separately-packages utility [`apt-show-versions`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt-show-versions) that, again, gives the information you want in roughly the format you're asking.

```
apt-show-versions | grep '^libav'
```

Comment: apt-show-versions works well enough for my purpose, thanks. I had not heard of this utility before. I see it uses what appear to be perl bindings to apt,      
namely libapt-pkg-perl. I guess python-apt would work too. Thanks. +1 and accepted.