# Find packages not maintained in main repo?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [listing packages in Debian, a la `dpkg -l`, but including the package origin/source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10220/listing-packages-in-debian-a-la-dpkg-l-but-including-the-package-origin-sou)

E.g. Ubuntu Server offers only security updates for software contained in the main repository - how can I check, which installed packages are / are not in the main repo? Thanks!